# Override Eloquent/Model __call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to override the default [`__call`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___call) method for [`Eloquent/Model`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php), but without luck.

I have tried the following:

```
function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    die("test");
}

static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    die("test2");
}
```

But it simply doesn't die, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `__construct()` at the top of your `controller` it works for all `function calls`

```
public function __construct() {
    echo '=========>test';
    exit;       
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I am trying to make this effect to a `model`, not a `controller`.